# perl one liner to preserve line endings

Tags: windows, perl, line-endings

I use the following perl one liner to search and replace pattern in files:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/pattern/replacement/g" file
```

The problem is that on Windows perl replaces line endings with Windows-style. I need to preserve the line endings whatever they are. Is there a command line option or something else to accomplish that? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: See also [perlport](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines), and the `:crlf` layer

Answer (score 0):

If you were talking about a `:utf8` layer, you could use the following:

```
perl -i.bak -CSD -pe"s///" file
```

But there's no option for `:raw`.

---

If you were talking about an `:encoding` layer, you could use the following:

```
perl -i.bak -Mopen=:std,:encoding(...) -pe"s///" file
```

But `:raw` is not supported by `use open`.

---

When using `-i` specifically (i.e. when not using using STDIN or STDOUT), the following will do what you want:

```
set PERLIO=:raw
perl -i.bak -pe"s///" file
set PERLIO=
```

Comment: When wanting to set a temporary environment variable for a script, it is easy to just include that before the command. I think this is portable across all shells.
> PERLIO=:raw perl -i.bak -pe"s///" file

Comment: @UncleCarl, It is most definitely not portable to all shells. In particular, it's not supported by the one used here.